# Writing a realtime joint controller [Tutorial]

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am doing the "[Writing a realtime joint controller](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)" tutorial. So far I have followed it closely and have checked that the plugin is visible to rospack using:

```
rospack plugins --attrib=plugin pr2_controller_interface
```

I can see the .xml file inside. Then when I go to the next tutorial, [Running a realtime joint controller](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller), it starts by launching the pr2 in Gazebo (which I do not want), rather I am using my own robot which publishes /joint_state, therefore I skipped to (4.) Running the Controller. I did the configuring but when I tried to check the status of other controllers by running:

```
rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list
```

I see nothing on the list. Does anyone what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54388/writing-a-realtime-joint-controller-%5Btutorial%5D/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you got it right with other questions. You need a specific code defining transmission in your robot URDF to pr2_controller_manager to be able to see it.

---

Originally posted by [IgorZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4123/igorz/) with karma: 86 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1